# jQGrid error when firing edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free jQGrid in it's latest version and jQuery Migrate 1.4.1 (1.6.x to 1.9.2) and jQuery UI 1.12.1.
After updating jQuery / jQuery UI edit form isn't working anymore!

**CODE:**

```
onInitializeForm: function(formid) {
    var form = $(formid).attr('id').split('-').pop();
    var id = $(formid).find('#id_g').val();
    var bt_gerar = $('<input />').attr('type', 'button').val('Gerar').click(function() {
        $(formid).find('input[name="senha"]').val(gerarPassword());
    });
    if (form === 'laudos') $(formid).find('input[name="senha"]').after(bt_gerar);
    if (form === 'usuarios') $(formid).find('input[name="senha"]').val('');
    $(formid).find('input[name="criacao"], input[name="exclusao"], input[name="data"]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
    /* UPLOAD LAUDO */
    var base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/_dev/";
    $('#arquivo').uploadify({
        'swf'  : base_url + 'admin/js/uploadify-new/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'    : base_url + 'admin/js/uploadify-new/uploadify.php?laudo=true',
        'cancelImage' : base_url + 'admin/img/cancel.png',
        'buttonImage' : base_url + 'admin/img/upload_mini.png',
        'wmode'     : 'transparent',
        'width'     : '20',
        'height'    : '20',
        'auto'      : true,
        'multi'     : false,
        'fileExt'   : '*.pdf',
        'fileDesc'  : 'Arquivo PDF (.PDF)',
        'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $('#arquivo').before($('<input />').attr({type:'text',id:'arquivo_temp',class:'FormElement',name:'arquivo',value:response,role:'textbox'}));
            $('#arquivo, #arquivoUploader, #arquivoQueue').remove();
            $('#arquivo_temp').attr('id','arquivo').hide();
            $('#arquivo').after($('<img />').attr({src:'/laudos/pdf.png',id:'arquivo_icone'}));
        }
    });
```

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: $(...).closest(...).attr(...).replace is not a function
```

**FILE:** ***jquery.jqgrid.src.js*** at line ***19319***

**CODE ERROR LINE:**

```
$id = $(this).closest("table.ui-jqgrid-btable").attr("id").replace(/_frozen([^_]*)$/, "$1")
```

Got any light?
Thk yu!

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the exact version of jqGrid, which you use. The line 19319 of  `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.6 contains `var insertPrefixAndSuffix = function (sOutput, opts) {` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js#L19319)). The statement "I'm using free jQGrid in it's latest version" gives not much enough information.

The line `$id = $(this).closest("table.ui-jqgrid-btable").attr("id").replace(/_frozen([^_]*)$/, "$1")`, which you posted, has the line number 19319 in the version 4.13.5 of free jqGrid. The code is inside of `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions`. Thus you have probably some problems with the usage of `formatter: "actions"`, but you don't included `colModel` with the corresponding column. The method `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` will be called in `onclick` of actions buttons, which must be inside of jqGrid, which must have `ui-jqgrid-btable` class.

It's difficult for me to guess, why you get the error. Either you made some illegal modifications of jqGrid classes (like removing `ui-jqgrid-btable` class) or you moved the grid content (inclusive the actions buttons) outside of jqGrid content or some other strange things. In any way you should include the definition of the column of `colModel`, which uses `formatter: "actions"`.

By the way, free jqGrid supports [template: "actions"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L176-L193), which you can use instead of `formatter: "actions"`. The `template: "actions"` is the shortcut of the following settings

```
formatter: "actions", align: "center", label: "", autoResizable: false, frozen: true,
fixed: true, hidedlg: true, resizable: false, sortable: false,
search: false, editable: false, viewable: false
```

and `width` setting, which value depend on some other options of jqGrid. The most of the properties are strictly recommended for the column with `formatter: "actions"` (even for old versions of jqGrid).

I'd recommend you to update to free jqGrid 4.13.6 and to replace `formatter: "actions"` to `template: "actions"` (or add `editable: false` and other above properties in the actions column alternatively). I hope that it will fix your problem.